# How can i get current set of tags passed from behave command

Tags: python, python-behave

I am new to Behave BDD. I want to go some logic based on the tags passed in command line. when I do context.tags/ context.scenario.tags I will get all the tags defined in the for that scenario. How can I get only the tags which are passed from the command line

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The tags you're passing to the CLI aren't actually tags you *set*, but rather tags you *select* for execution (or exclusion of execution, depending on how you're passing them). I'd say only Behave's runner has access to this data.

If you want to achieve different behavior based on parameters passed to the CLI, use the `--define` option (see [here](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html#cmdoption-D))

Then all you have to do is retrieve your data via `context.config.userdata`
Say you wanted to define the parameter x, you'd call Behave like this:

```
behave --define x=1 test.feature
```

And then retrieve the defined data in your step definitions, like this:

```
x = context.config.userdata['x']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from context.config._tags if you really need it.
It should return list of strings with tags/tag expressions.

For example, when you run behave:

```
beahve --tags ~@fixme --tags @buggy,@test
```

context.config._tags will have value:

```
['~@fixme', '@buggy,@test']
```